# Troubles with NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to create an NSMutableArray inside of a new ViewController but it doesn't seems to work.

I'm trying to use this code

```
self.title = @"list";

list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", Nil];
```

Comment: You need to explain what does not seem to work. "It doesn't seems to work." does not help us help you.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so, what error are you getting?

Comment: What kind of trouble do you get? (The last item should be `nil` with the lowercase `n`).

Answer (score 3):

Your example appears fine ***mostly***:

```
- (void)hypotheticalMethod
{
    NSMutableArray *list; //<--Where is this?

    //Turn your Nil into nil
    list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];

    NSLog(@"list is: %@", list);
}
```

Comment: and your method is fine — mostly. If used without ARC this code would be leaking.

Comment: I would hope that the OP knows this, otherwise, if he is interested, he can ask about it in another thread.  I also don't condone the use of NSLog - just so long as he understands the key point of the answer.

Comment: sure, but I think, if you are about to give a full-functioning block of code, you should at least mention it, as a newbie might over-see it.

Comment: Point taken.  Never said it was fully functional ;)  Upvoted your comment.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

you didn't explain, what gos wrong, but `Nil` is a NULL-class pointer, you want `nil` for null-objetcs.

```
 list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", nil];
```

Comment: They're equivalent; this wouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: It would be good to know, what the problems are.

Comment: You're right to point it out. I should've been clearer; I just meant that both `nil` and `Nil` have the same value, so they will function equivalently in this case.